# How to Replace XML Node Using R

Tags: r, xml

I am using package "XML" to create an XML file in R.

Here is my R code.

```
library(XML)
xmlWARN <- xmlParse(strWarningXMLFileName)
xmlWARN <- xmlRoot(xmlWARN)
newXMLNode("StartDateTime", format(min(MyData$timestamp),"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), parent = xmlWARN)       
newXMLNode("EndDateTime", format(max(MyData$timestamp),"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"), parent = xmlWARN)
newXMLNode("Granularity", strGranularity, parent = xmlWARN)
newXMLNode("TimeGapInData",blnTimeSlotGaps , parent = xmlWARN)
newXMLNode("TimeGapInDataIntervals",intNumberOfMissingTimeslots , parent = xmlWARN)
newXMLNode("IncompleteTimespan",blnIncompleteTimeSpan , parent = xmlWARN)
saveXML(xmlWARN, strWarningXMLFileName)
```

This creates my XML file below just fine.

```
<Server-Block>
  <Platform>LINUX</Platform>
  <ServerName>MyServer</ServerName>
  <StartDateTime>08/12/2017 00:00</StartDateTime>
  <EndDateTime>08/12/2017 11:00</EndDateTime>
  <Granularity>1-minute</Granularity>
  <TimeGapInData>FALSE</TimeGapInData>
  <TimeGapInDataIntervals>0</TimeGapInDataIntervals>
  <IncompleteTimespan>FALSE</IncompleteTimespan>
  <AtLeastOneThresholdExceeded>TRUE</AtLeastOneThresholdExceeded>
  <LinuxCPUUtilizationPercentCollected>TRUE</LinuxCPUUtilizationPercentCollected>
  <LinuxCPUUtilizationPercentWithoutWIOThresholdMaximum>80</LinuxCPUUtilizationPercentWithoutWIOThresholdMaximum>
  <LinuxCPUUtilizationPercentWithoutWIOThresholdMaximumExceeded>TRUE</LinuxCPUUtilizationPercentWithoutWIOThresholdMaximumExceeded>
  <LinuxCPUUtilizationPercentWithoutWIOThresholdMaximumReached>98.887</LinuxCPUUtilizationPercentWithoutWIOThresholdMaximumReached>
  <LinuxCPUUtilizationPercentWithoutWIOThresholdAverageReached>9.04793040847201</LinuxCPUUtilizationPercentWithoutWIOThresholdAverageReached>
  <LinuxCPUUtilizationPercentWithoutWIOThresholdMaximumReachedCount>25</LinuxCPUUtilizationPercentWithoutWIOThresholdMaximumReachedCount>
  <StartDateTime>08/12/2017 00:00</StartDateTime>
  <EndDateTime>08/12/2017 11:00</EndDateTime>
  <Granularity>1-minute</Granularity>
  <TimeGapInData>FALSE</TimeGapInData>
  <TimeGapInDataIntervals>0</TimeGapInDataIntervals>
  <IncompleteTimespan>FALSE</IncompleteTimespan>
</Server-Block>
```

The only thing I cannot figure out is how to replace the value for a node.

For instance change:

```
<ServerName>MyServer</ServerName>
```

to

```
<ServerName>YourServer</ServerName>
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Lou

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps!

```
library(XML)
#test.xml is the xml file where you want to make changes
xml_doc = xmlParseDoc("test.xml")
#replace the value of 'ServerName' node
invisible(replaceNodes(xml_doc[["//Server-Block//ServerName/text()"]], newXMLTextNode("YourServer")))
xml_doc
```

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem :)*

Comment: @user7945126 if it solved your problem then you should mark it as correct answer. It'll certainly help others in case they face similar issue in future. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to change <pageUrl> content in vain. Can you please help?  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CheckInFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <pageUrl>https://mysharepointserver.com/sites/mysite/myfile.txt</pageUrl>
      <comment>Automagic update</comment>
      <checkinType>0</checkinType>
    </CheckInFile>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: @RanonKahn Please create a new post so that others can also help. BTW you might be interested in this XPath definition - `'//*[name()="soap:Envelope"]`

Comment: Actually I created a post here yesterday.    https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225026/how-to-check-in-file-in-sharepoint-using-r

Comment: @RanonKahn Let's try this - `library(XML); xml_doc = xmlParseDoc("test.xml");
invisible(replaceNodes(getNodeSet(xml_doc, "//ns:CheckInFile//ns:pageUrl/text()", c(ns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"))[[1]], 
                       newXMLTextNode("YournewPageUrl"))); xml_doc`. Hope it helps!

Comment: Perfect! Can you please copy this answer to the  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225026/how-to-check-in-file-in-sharepoint-using-r query so that I can accept your answer?

Comment: Glad that it helped :) I believe this question should have been posted to SO for better and quick response.

Comment: Apologies I forgot to respond back. This solved my issue. Thanks so much!!